# Sorting function sort() does not work as expected in a specific case

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am pretty new to Python and am solving basic problem to learn my way into Python. In this process, I was trying out the `sort()` function to sort a list in the ascending order.

Increasing digits of the same numbers are sorted together even when they're not supposed to. For example, numbers `6`, `66`, `666` and so on are not supposed to be together if there is a number between them.

I have tried using different kinds of inputs, but everything gets grouped together like the following:

```
(base) C:\Data\Personal Data\Python>python test.py
10

1
11
111
1111
2
22
222
2222
3
33
['1', '11', '111', '1111', '2', '22', '222', '2222', '3', '33']
```

Following is the code written for this purpose:

```
t = int(input()) #Accepts user input for number of iterations
n = []

for i in range(t):
    u = input()
    n.append(u)

n.sort() 
print(n)
```

Although I haven't seen any error messages as such, the outputs are definitely what I expected them to be. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're sorting strings, not numbers, and the solution lies in your very code, just use `int` when reading all the numbers in the same way you're using it when reading the number of iterations:

```
for i in range(t):
    u = int(input())
    n.append(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you take input as numbers in string format in `list`, you can sort these using `map` and `lambda` function.
Just use lambda function inside sort function.

```py
n.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
```